# HTML 4 Entities

Tags: html, char, entities

Is there a concise way to scan an html script for entities it is unfamiliar with and import them with their html codes?  All I'm getting in place of a 'degree celsius' character, for example, is a question mark.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you're not declaring character encoding. What you need to do is this:

In your `<head>` element, insert the following code:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1">
```

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta) from MDN

[Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_charset.asp) from W3Schools